# How to press the arrow keys with python keyboard libray?

Tags: python

Im trying to make a bot for a game. I need to press the left arrow key but it does not move the camera at all. I think it is using the arrow keys on the numpad and not the 4 arrow keys. How do I fix this?

```
keyboard.press("left arrow")
time.sleep(0.5)
keyboard.release("left arrow")
```

I tried differnt libraries like pyautogui but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same with `pyautogui`, and `keyboard`. Just use the word for direction. For example, 'right', or 'left'. Like this:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('left') #presses left arrow key
```

I recommend looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/README.md) to find key codes, as to find the difference between arrows on the numpad and normal layout can be difficult, and just for general reference in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet to access the arrow keys.
I have made use of the [keyboard library](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) inorder to do that.

1. **UP ARROW KEY**  -> **"up"**
2. **DOWN ARROW KEY** -> **"down"**
3. **LEFT ARROW KEY** -> **"left"**
4. **RIGHT ARROW KEY** -> **"right"**

Here is a sample code

```
import keyboard

# To Press UP ARROW KEY
keyboard.press("up")
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I was wondering why the OP was using "left arrow" instead of just "left". I always did it your way @Ashwin Balasubramanian, does this press the keys on the numpad though?

Comment: I think It won't be pressing the keys in numpad since you are pressing it using python script. But it will matter when you are tracking which keys are pressed, if your numlock is turned on then the arrows in the numpad will be considered as numbers if not it will be considered as arrow keys.